# Subdirectory mapping for a WordPress website

Tags: subdomains, domain-mapping, dns

I have created a website on WordPress. Now I want to create a subdirectory mapping such that

```
mywordpress-site.com/french
```

points to

```
mywordpress-site.com
```

How could I do this? Is this possible with WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways. You're simply wanting to redirect the reference /french to the site root or map all URL's that go with it?
The 'Redirection' plugin would be a starting point https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Not sure if that's exactly what you're after though?

Comment: Redirect would be different. I want to retain the address on browser. Redirection won't.